# React_native: Error undefined is not a function (evaluating 'data.forEach) ListView Error

Tags: react-native

I am having problem with dynamic data assignment to datasource of listview.
I have made a web-service call in constructor which returns jsonArray and then after receiving I have assigned received data (JSONArray) to DataSource of Listview.

```
  `constructor(props){
  let data= this.getActivityCalenderList();
  const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,
    sectionHeaderHasChanged: (s1, s2) => s1 !== s2});
  this.state = {
  dataSource: ds.cloneWithRowsAndSections(this.convertArrayToMap(data))}
  }
  }
  render()
  {
   return(
     <ListView  dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={(data) =><View>.....</View>}/>}
     renderSectionHeader={(sectionData, startdatetime)=><View>....</View>}
  );
  }`
```

Problem is before data assignment Listview is getting rendered (static data assignement is working).
Any help or suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try conditional rendering by creating a dataObtained state variable. Make the api call on componentWillMount and show the list view only when data is obtained. Hope this helps!

```
constructor(props){
  const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
   rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
  });
  this.state = {
    dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([]),
    dataObtained: false,
  }
}

componentWillMount (){
    let data = this.getActivityCalenderList();
    this.setState({dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(data), 
                   dataObtained:true});
}

render()
{
  if(this.state.dataObtained){
    return(
      <ListView  dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
       renderRow={(data) =><View>.....</View>}/>}
       renderSectionHeader={(sectionData, startdatetime)=><View>....
       </View>}
    );
  }else{
    return(
      <View>
        <ActivityIndicator/>
      </View>
    );
  }

}`
```